# Breaking up css class definitions?

Tags: html, css

What would be the reason to break css class definitions like this?

```
.myclass {
    padding: 10px;
}
.myclass {
    background: #03949;
}
```

Is there any advantage?

Comment: no advantage, it's usually an accident or they're grouping their CSS by something other than the selector, like page name/section or something.

Comment: I don't see much reason to separate them if they are on the same style sheet. They will be applied in the order they are listed (so padding would come before background).

Comment: In HTML, you can give an element multiple class names (separated by space), like `<p class="text paragraph greeting">Hello World</p>`

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. This would definitely be considered bad code as it doesn't keep your CSS dry (as simple as possible). You might use something like this though:

```
.myClass {
   padding: 10px;
}

.myClass, .mySecondClass {
   background: #03949;
}
```

This would be helpful if you only wanted one element to have padding but you wanted two elements to have a background color. Hope this helps!